# ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[""] is null while using in data access layer(DAL) for windows forms

Tags: winforms, mvp, n-tier-architecture

I am using Model view presenter(MVP) architecture in my windows form application. Everything is fine. But during data access I faced the problem that ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[""] is null, so I can not make any database interactions.

Design of my DAL layer:
First I added a class library project. Then added a data source to the project. This added an app.config to my DAL project with the necessary connection string. Then some classes to make the database handling. There in initializing my connection string
**private string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SimpleBilling_MVP_Ribbon.DAL.Properties.Settings.Test_SimpleBillingDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;**

Here I got the exception 'argument out of range' as configurationManager.ConnectionStrings[""] is null.

My findings:
1) Some said, app.config should be one for the whole application and so should reside in the application entry project. But where I am supposed to keep that, View is not the proper place as after all DAL is going to need it.

2) I made some search and came to know that configurationManager.ConnectionStrings[""] can not be used in a class library project(DLL) in straight way. I got some code project articles to demonstrate the use of the same in a DLL using some work around.

But in my case it is not just a DLL with the need to handle configurationManager. All MVP will be having the same necessity to handle database in the same way? So how people are doing this?

Your experienced thought will be very helpful here.